# Build custom layout based on several different preferences

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences

In my onConfigure for a widget, I use a preference fragment and allow users to edit the font style, color, and size when they add the widget.  I understand how I can edit a layout when there only a couple of customization settings, something like this:

```
if (pref == 1){
    setContentView(layout1)
} else{
    setContentView(layout2)
}
```

But my widget allows for a near infinite amount of possibilities, so instead of spending the next few lifetimes accounting for all those possibilities by making pre built layouts, how can I do this on the fly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change: font style, color, and size. You can do it in program by using

```
findViewById(R.id.XXXX)
```

where R.id.XXX is the widget. Then you can change them by setting the style, color and size in code.